# How to identify duplicate assemblies?

Tags: .net, reflection

While l was looking over some questions about MEF, I stumbled onto [this particular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708018/how-to-prevent-module-duplicates-with-mef/1709483#1709483) to a question.  It made me wonder about such a bit since I've never had to attempt such but can see it being very valid in the scenario of that question.

**Scenario:**
If you have a directory of various .Net Assemblies all named different, how would you be able to identify ones that may be the same but renamed (i.e. Copy Of MyAssembly.dll vs MyAssembly.dll)?

I can think of the following items:

1. Check File Size (should be the same)
2. Check Assembly Version Number
3. Loop through the assembly using Reflection and attempt to locate any differences.

Is there any other/easier way of addressing this issue?  Are there other criteria to look at for determining if 2 differently named DLLs are in fact the same compiled Assembly?

Comment: @james, you say that you were "really looking for a programmatic solution". Check the code, is this coming a bit closer? Let us know where we can improve.

Comment: @Abel I'm hoping to test this out tonight.  I wasn't able to like I was hoping to last night so hopefully I'll know more tonight.  Will let you know/mark an answer tonight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first I thought you could use the `Equals` or `ReferenceEquals` to do this, but this proofs too error prone. If you use `Assembly.LoadFile`, this will not work, for instance.

With nUnit, I did the following tests, which are a bit basic, but gives you something to go on. The weird way of loading the types is necessary (see MSDN). I assume you know how to do the "quick tests" in case you want to check for binary equality etc (see PS below).

```
Assembly asm1 = Assembly.LoadFile(@"someDebugAssembly.dll");
Assembly asm2 = Assembly.LoadFile(@"someReleaseAssembly.dll");

// load all the types (the double try/catch is on purpose)
Type[] types1 = null
Type[] types2 = null;
try
{
    types1 = asm1.GetTypes();
}
catch (ReflectionTypeLoadException e)
{
    types1 = e.Types;
}
try 
{
    types2 = asm1.GetTypes();
}
catch (ReflectionTypeLoadException e)
{
    types2 = e.Types;
}

// same length
Assert.AreEqual(types1.Length, types2.Length);

// check each type
IEnumerator types1Enumerator =  types1.GetEnumerator();
types1Enumerator.Reset();
foreach (Type t in types2)
{
    types1Enumerator.MoveNext();
    Assert.AreEqual(types1Enumerator.Current, t);
}
```

A note on the code: this method of comparison will treat two assemblies as equal when they contain the same types. This means that a debug and a release build, or different versions, are not taken into consideration. Use `asm1.GetName()` and its properties (again: do not use Equals!) to compare the individual strings (version, full name etc).

PS: it would be intriguing to define what constitutes two equal assemblies, i.e.:

1. they are binary equal
2. there versions and fully qualified names are equal
3. the strong names are equal
4. all types, deeply compared, have equal signatures

depending on what you choose, two entirely different assemblies (i.e. debug build vs release build) can come up as equal. It really depends on how you want to compare.

***Update:*** corrected previous errors and added code sample

Comment: Depends on how you load them http://blogs.msdn.com/suzcook/archive/2003/05/29/57143.aspx

Comment: @erik: Correct, I was coming to the same conclusion while testing. I'm editing the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'll go first for a simple quick check using point 1. and 2., that is checking file size and assembly version number. If they're all different well, you're done.

If not, keep the files who have the same file size / version and compute their MD5/SHA1/whatever-you-prefer hash. If the hash is the same, you're definitely in presence of the same assembly twice. Since assemblies generally aren't very large (at most a few megabytes), the hash computing should be fast enough.

Comment: No, two assemblies can end up with the same hash (pigeonhole principle). To be completely certain, you have to compare them byte by byte.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You can also use the good old **comp** command line program:</strike>

> ```
> c:\tests> comp one.dll two.dll
> Comparing one.dll and two.dll...
> Files compare OK
> ```

**Update:** even better. Download the [Windows XP Service Pack 2 support tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=49ae8576-9bb9-4126-9761-ba8011fabf38&DisplayLang=en), install it (choose **Complete installation**). Then go to the 'Run command' dialog and type **dupfinder**. Point it to the folder that you want you'll start seing all the duplicates in that path and its subfolders.

Comment: Was really looking for a .net/programmatic answer but I didn't specify such so was my fault there.  Definitely good to know though since I wasn't aware of dupfinder.  Thanks

Comment: Then I would first compare sizes, then use something like Mono.Cecil to inspect the assembly name/version/signature (if signed) without actually loading the assembly. Then, if the assembly is not signed, just compare byte by byte...